Page Loader Stuck When Clicking Browser Back Button in .NET MVC Website
I'm developing a website using .NET MVC, which can be accessed at https://gengecmimarlik.com . The site uses a page loader animation that works as expected during normal navigation through the navbar links. However, I encounter an issue when using the browser’s back button.
Problem:
When I navigate to a different page (e.g., /TumProjeler or /iletisim) and then press the back button on the browser (Chrome or Edge), the loader animation appears but stays stuck, preventing the page from loading properly. The site doesn't crash or throw any errors, but the loader does not disappear, and the page content doesn’t show up.
If I remove the preloader, the problem disappears, but I need to keep it for design purposes.
Key Details:

I’m not using any AJAX calls for page transitions; the navigation is
straightforward.
All routes and navigation links are configured properly.
Here is a sample of how the links are set up in the navbar:

<a class="rd-nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Ana Sayfa</a>
<a class="rd-nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AllProjects">Tüm Projeler</a>
<a class="rd-nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#ekibimiz">Ekibimiz</a>
<a class="rd-nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">İletişim</a>


I’m using a preloader that runs when the page loads. However, it
seems to get stuck when navigating back using the browser’s back
button.
What could be causing the page loader to get stuck when the back button is pressed? Are there specific .NET MVC behaviors or browser caching settings that I need to adjust? How can I ensure that the loader doesn’t hang and the content loads properly when users go back to the previous page?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Edit: The repo below contains the HTML of the loader and the scripts used by the loader. I couldn't add all of them to the problem due to the character class. If this is a behavior that does not comply with the rules, I apologize, I am relatively new to stackoverflow.
https://github.com/onurkaygn/loader
If you think the problem is not with the scripts but with something else, I can share the other folders as well.

This should include the actual code of your page loader animation, so that we can see how exactly it determines a page has finished loading.

onload will fire when you use back... but I don't think that script is going to be re-initialized, so it's existing state is telling that script to show the animation. You might want to avoid lazy-loading altogether.

I tried what you said but it didn't work.
Sorry for not pushing all codes. Now i updated the github repo you can check from here.

You can try just clearing state onLoad.... (I couldn't determine what vars need clearing from a quick look at your code there...)  See here for onload: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Add these lines of code in the "Global.asax.cs" file i.e.
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
} 

